# How to get browser history in android

Tags: android, browser, android-contentprovider

Is there any way that a firefox browser history can be read using content provider.
I am able to read crome browser history.

Comment: you should search for that browsers' API available. Each browser has it's own API. Additionally, you may be missing other browsers, Mozilla for example.

Comment: do you know api for these browsers , as i have tried to searched but didn't find any usefull link.

Comment: can anyone plz help how to set permissions of firefox , this url also getting same error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980131/how-do-i-programmatically-access-bookmarks-in-opera-and-mozilla-browsers-for-and

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get firefox history uri like the chrome provide, i have asked the question on support team of firefox.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1162505